# How to make Oracle accept any password for login?

Tags: oracle, authentication, logins, oracle-8i

We have an old application which we need data and reports from. The application is configured to retrieve data from Oracle DB and the login username and password are hardcoded in the application. However, we do not have the source code as it was lost, we only have the exe.

We have recovered a database dump and were able to successfully point the app to the database, but we are getting wrong password errors and we cannot find out the old password to change the password to.

Is there anyway Oracle can accept login requests using **any** password provided so the application can log in successfully?

Comment: Do you know the username? You could run `strings` on the executable and see if any of the strings output near the username work. If you're really lucky, maybe it spits out the entire connection string...

Comment: I do know the username. How can I run `strings` ?

Comment: On Linux it's probably already installed. On Windows, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/strings

Comment: What type of application is it, i.e. in which language is it written?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit it is written in VB 6, but the developer is long gone from the company and none of us have any development expertise, so we have no idea how to get data from the exe, if there is a way.

Comment: Perhaps this one helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/414068/is-there-a-visual-basic-6-decompiler

Comment: Accept any password? No. Authenticate using only the username? Yes, it is possible using local/remote OS authentication, but it will not work without modifying the application (works with sqlplus, no idea about VB).

Comment: @BalazsPapp the problem is we cannot modify the application, it'll keep trying to connect via the old method.

Comment: Another suggestion is to attach a debugger to the process and step through it.

Comment: I don't think attaching a debugger to a VB6 .exe is possible - unless you have helper files like .pdb and source code. VB6 is not .NET.

Comment: What version of Oracle and which operating system on the server and client?

Comment: @DmitryDemin Oracle server was originally Oracle 8, OS for server originally was Windows 2000 server but we restored the data dump on Oracle 11gR2 on Oracle Linux 6.4, and client OS (where the app is running) is Windows 7.